# Troubleshootings with encoding

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, character-encoding

I am working on j2ee project. It is supposed to work width both english and russian language. So I have an EncodingFilter which has mapping ' /* ' and every time do one thing: `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

I also have MySQL 5.5 installed, the charset of tables and databases is set to `utf-8` and collation to  `utf8_general_ci`.

On my local machine everything works just fine, Russian lang properly stores in db.

Then I tried to test my app on jelastic.com . There I also selected MySQL, imported dump, set charset to `utf-8` and collation to `utf8_general_ci`. When I am adding russian words to db I only see '?????'. But elder records which came with dump are fine! I have literaly no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Where exactly do you see "?????"? In the DB by some DB admin tool? Or in HTTP response?

Comment: I am using phpMyAdmin. But as said by '??????' marked only new records, elder which are from dump are fine. So i think phpMyAdmin do not have influence on my situation.

Comment: It was just a question to exclude one and other :) I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the MySQL JDBC driver to use UTF-8 as client side encoding instead of the platform default one. If the platform default charset is not UTF-8, then this will result in `?` being stored in the database whenever a character is not covered by the platform default charset which the JDBC driver is using.

You could do that by adding the `useUnicode=yes` and `characterEncoding=UTF-8` parameters to the JDBC URL. E.g.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

That it works on your local Java development environment is likely because you've already configured the platform default charset of your environment to be UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You know, internalization can be a real ***pain)

Comment: this is because Americans does not care about more countries;)